# Вылетает приложение

Tags: java, android

Последний мой вопрос на ближайшее время..
вот код ScreenOne

```
    package com.example.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class ScreenOne extends Activity {


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.screen_one);
        }




        GeoPoint currentLocation = new GeoPoint(formatLocation(null), formalLoc(null), "hhh");

        private double formalLoc(Location location) {
                return
                        location.getLongitude();
        }

        private double formatLocation(Location location) {
                 return
                location.getLatitude();



        }




        GeoPoint locations[] = new GeoPoint[]{
new GeoPoint(55.11, 37.11, "N1"),
                new GeoPoint(55.22, 37.22, "N2"),
                new GeoPoint(55.33, 37.33, "N3"),
 };






        GeoPoint nearest = GeoPoint.getNearestLocation(currentLocation,
                Arrays.asList(locations));


        public void onClick(View view) {
                TextView helloTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.station_name);
                helloTextView.setText(nearest.getName());
        }

}
```

Приложение при запуске вылетает..(аварийно закрывается). в чем проблема?
вот еще GeoPoint, может с ним?..

```
package com.example.app;

import android.location.Location;

import java.util.Collection;

public class GeoPoint {

    public final double lat;
    public final double lon;
    public String name;

    public GeoPoint(double lat, double lon, String name) {
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lon = lon;
        this.name = name;
    }



    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public GeoPoint(Location location) {
        this.lat = location.getLatitude();
        this.lon = location.getLongitude();
    }

    public static GeoPoint getNearestLocation(GeoPoint current, Collection<GeoPoint> locations) {
        GeoPoint res = null;
        float lastDisance = Float.MAX_VALUE;
        float locDistance[] = new float[1];
        for (GeoPoint loc: locations) {
            Location.distanceBetween(current.lat, current.lon,
                    loc.lat, loc.lon, locDistance);
            if (res == null || locDistance[0] < lastDisance) {
                res = loc;
                lastDisance = locDistance[0];
            }
        }
        return res;
    }




}
```

Comment: что лог пишет? .

Comment: Вы в стактрейс смотрели? Там есть и строчка, в которой ошибка, и тип ошибки.

Comment: уже разобрался..только теперь уже другой вопрос. сейчас новый задам..

Answer (score 3):

Очевидно, вот из-за этой статической инициализации:

```
GeoPoint currentLocation = new GeoPoint(formatLocation(null), formalLoc(null), "hhh");
```

Здесь вы используете методы `formatLocation` и `formatLoc`, в которые передаете `null`, но в самом методе не проверяете, не является ли параметр типа Location `null'ом`.

Отсюда и ошибка - `NullPointerException`.

И, действительно, заглядывайте в stacktrace - подобные нелепые ошибки сможете исправлять самостоятельно.

Comment: так, сейчас будет..